# Password not resetting in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

Here is a snap of ResetPasswords class:

```
$response = Password::broker($broker)->reset($credentials, function ($user, $password) {
    $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
});
```

If I print the `$response` variable it always returns `password.token`, but it should return `password.reset` instead.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Just to make sure we're on the same page, are you using Laravel's defaults? Why would you want to use something different?

Comment: yes im using laravel defaults

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`passwords.reset` is returned when the password is successfully reset.

`passwords.token` is returned when the reset token is not valid.

Other possible return values are:

`passwords.user` is returned when the user cannot be found.

`passwords.password` is returned when the password does not pass validation.

You can see the password broker reset function [here (Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker::reset)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.php#L129-L150).

That function calls the `validateReset()` method (shown [here (Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker::validateReset)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.php#L158-L173)).

The values of the constants returned by that method are defined on the password broker interface (contract). You can view this [here (Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Contracts/Auth/PasswordBroker.php).

Comment: on my project i used multi table authentication.i guest confusion is happening there.How can i solve this

Comment: @moinkhan That will probably highly depend on your application. I do not have experience with multi table auth. I would start here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#resetting-passwords

Comment: can you share me a complete tutorial of password rest in laravel